# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0}\Big({\frac 1{x^2} - \frac 1{\sin^2x}}\Big)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How to solve :$$\lim_{x\to0}\Big(\frac 1{x^2} - \frac 1{\sin^2x}\Big)$$
**My approach** :
*as* $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac {\sin x}x}=1$.
*Therefore when* $x\to0$ , $\sin x=x$.
*So when* $x\to0$ , $\frac 1{X^2}=\frac 1{\sin^2x}$.
*So the answer to the problem is* $0$.
*But in the book answer is given* $\frac 13$ .
*How?*

Comment: Oops sorry I did'nt know someone already asked it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x\approx x-x^3/6+...\\
\sin^2x\approx x^2(1-x^2/3+...)\\
\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\approx x^{-2}(1-x^2/3+...)^{-1}\\
=x^{-2}+1/3+...$$

Comment: So, the limit is $-\frac 13$ which is what I was typing when arrived your answer. Can we suppose one more typo in a textbook ?

Comment: I suppose so, I have a typo in this answer...

Answer (score 0):

You used that in $$\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{\sin^2x}=\frac1{x^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\right) $$
the expression parenthesis tends $\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. However, $\frac1{x^2}$ does not remain bounded and in fact grows fast enough to cancel the effect.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me understand the situation here.